# Is the MIDIPacket timestamp ignored when using CoreMIDI's MIDISend?

Tags: coremidi

It is unclear to me whether the timestamp field can be used to schedule MIDI events in the future, i.e., to happen after the call to MIDISend. The following code attempts to schedule 10 note ons and 10 note offs every second. The timestamps should specify that the note's note off happen 1/10th of a second after the the note on, however on all the hardware or virtual destinations I have tried, it seems all the events are sent immediately when MIDISend is called. Is this the general behaviour or does some MIDI hardware / do some virtual MIDI destinations support the the proper scheduling of events using the timestamp value? Here is my code:

```
/* send_midi_port.c
 * Open connection with destination (rather than setting up MIDI source) and send
 * timestamped messages
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CoreMIDI.h> 
#include <HostTime.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STR_BUFSIZE 200 

#define ERR_EXIT(x)\
    fprintf(stderr,"Error %s\n",x);\
return -1;

typedef void (*sig_t) (int);

static volatile int done = 0;

static mach_timebase_info_data_t sTimebaseInfo;

void int_handle(int signum)
{
    done = 1;
}

char *CFString_strncpy(char *dest,
        CFStringRef str,
        size_t n)
{
    CFStringEncoding encoding = kCFStringEncodingUTF8;
    if (!CFStringGetCString(str, dest, n, encoding)) {
        dest = NULL;
    }
    return dest;
}

int CFString_cstr_strncmp(CFStringRef s1, char *s2, size_t n)
{
    char buf[STR_BUFSIZE];
    if (CFString_strncpy(buf, s1, STR_BUFSIZE) == NULL) {
        return -2;
    }
    return strncmp(buf,s2,n);
}

/* Print CFString to stdout */
void CFString_printf(CFStringRef str)
{
    char buffer[STR_BUFSIZE];
    CFStringEncoding encoding = kCFStringEncodingUTF8;
    const char *ptr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(str, encoding);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        if (CFStringGetCString(str, buffer, STR_BUFSIZE, encoding)) {
            ptr = buffer;
        }
    }
    if (ptr) {
        printf("%s",ptr);
    }
}

/* Get MIDI object's name as CFStringRef */
CFStringRef MIDIObjectRef_get_name(MIDIObjectRef obj)
{
    CFStringRef name = NULL;
    OSStatus err;
    err = MIDIObjectGetStringProperty(obj,kMIDIPropertyName,&name);
    if (err) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return name;
} 

UInt64 nano_to_absolute(UInt64 nano)
{
    return nano * sTimebaseInfo.denom / sTimebaseInfo.numer;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Get Timebase info
    (void) mach_timebase_info(&sTimebaseInfo);

    char desired_dest_[] = "FastTrack Pro";
    char *desired_dest;
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("No device specified, using default output %s.\n", desired_dest_);
        desired_dest = desired_dest_;
    } else {
        desired_dest = argv[1];
    }

    ItemCount n_dests = MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations();
    int found = 0;
    MIDIEndpointRef desired_epr;
    while (n_dests--) {
        MIDIEndpointRef dest = MIDIGetDestination(n_dests);
        CFStringRef name = MIDIObjectRef_get_name(dest);
        if (CFString_cstr_strncmp(name,desired_dest,strlen(desired_dest))
                == 0) {
            printf(" Name of destination %d: ",(int)n_dests);
            CFString_printf(name);
            printf("\n");
            found = 1;
            desired_epr = dest;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        printf("Destination %s not found.\n",desired_dest);
        return -1;
    }
    OSStatus result;
    MIDIClientRef clientref;
    result = MIDIClientCreate(CFSTR("default"),NULL,NULL,&clientref);
    if (result < 0 ) {
        ERR_EXIT("Creating client.");
    }
    MIDIPortRef portref;
    result = MIDIOutputPortCreate(clientref,CFSTR("hiports"),&portref);
    if (result < 0 ) {
        ERR_EXIT("Creating port.");
    }
    signal(SIGINT,int_handle);
    while (!done) {
        // With multiple and time stamps
        ByteCount mpdsize = sizeof(MIDIPacketList)+sizeof(MIDIPacket)*20;
        char mpdata[mpdsize];
        memset(mpdata,0,mpdsize);
        MIDIPacketList *midipackets;
        midipackets = (MIDIPacketList*)mpdata;
        MIDIPacket *mp;
        mp = MIDIPacketListInit(midipackets);
        int n;
        UInt64 timeNano, timeScale;
        for (n = 0; n < 20; n += 2) {
            Byte noteOnData[3] = {0x90,60+(n/2),100};
            Byte noteOffData[3] = {0x80,60+(n/2),0};
            // on all the devices I tried, the timestamps seem to be ignored
            mp = MIDIPacketListAdd(midipackets,mpdsize,mp,
                    nano_to_absolute(((UInt64)n/2) * 100ULL * 1000ULL * 1000ULL),
                    // seems equivalent to 0
//                    0,
                    3,noteOnData);
            if (!mp) {
                ERR_EXIT("Adding MIDI packet.\n");
            }
            mp = MIDIPacketListAdd(midipackets,mpdsize,mp,
                    nano_to_absolute((((UInt64)n/2)+1) * 100ULL * 1000ULL * 1000ULL),
                    // seems equivalent to 0
//                    0,
                    3,noteOffData);
            if (!mp) {
                ERR_EXIT("Adding MIDI packet.\n");
            }
        }
        // Check packets
        printf("Number of packets: %d\n",(int)midipackets->numPackets);
        MIDIPacket *__p = &midipackets->packet[0];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < midipackets->numPackets; ++i) {
            printf("Timestamp: %llu\n"
                    "Length: %d\n"
                    "Data : ",
                    __p->timeStamp,
                    (int)__p->length);
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < __p->length; j++) {
                printf("%d ",(int)__p->data[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            __p = MIDIPacketNext(__p);
        }
        printf("Sending notes\n");
        MIDISend(portref,desired_epr,midipackets);
        sleep(1);
    }

    MIDIPortDispose(portref);
    MIDIClientDispose(clientref);

    return 0;
}
```

This can be built with the command (the paths to the frameworks might be different on your machine)

```
clang send_midi_port.c -o send_midi_port.bin - I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Headers -framework CoreMIDI -g -framework CoreFoundation -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers -framework CoreAudio -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers -framework CoreServices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `MIDIPacketListAdd`, you are not supplying a correct timestamp. You are passing in an offset from the current time, starting at 0 for the first event, and increasing with later events. But you are not including the current time.

As a result, CoreMIDI thinks the timestamps are in the past, so it sends the events immediately.

Use `AudioGetCurrentHostTime` to get the current time, and add each offset to that.

```
    UInt64 now = AudioGetCurrentHostTime();
    for (n = 0; n < 20; n += 2) {
        Byte noteOnData[3] = {0x90,60+(n/2),100};
        Byte noteOffData[3] = {0x80,60+(n/2),0};
        mp = MIDIPacketListAdd(midipackets,mpdsize,mp,
                now + nano_to_absolute(((UInt64)n/2) * 100ULL * 1000ULL * 1000ULL),
                3,noteOnData);
        mp = MIDIPacketListAdd(midipackets,mpdsize,mp,
                now + nano_to_absolute((((UInt64)n/2)+1) * 100ULL * 1000ULL * 1000ULL),
                3,noteOffData);
    }
```

When you use `MIDISend`, CoreMIDI will handle the scheduling, regardless of whether the end device is MIDI hardware, or a virtual MIDI destination owned by some other app.

Comment: This works, but the documentation is misleading. For MIDIReceived it says:  _Unlike MIDISend(), a timestamp of 0 is not equivalent to "now"; the driver or virtual source is responsible for putting proper timestamps in the packets_ implying that for MIDISend 0 means "now", which is clearly not true.

Comment: It does mean "now". If you pass a zero timestamp, the event will be sent as soon as possible. Have you observed otherwise? That's always the behavior I have seen. I was seeing that your first event (which had timestamp 0) was sent immediately... it's just that the other events with other timestamps were *also* sent immediately.

Comment: Yes because my example code doesn't work. If it did actually mean "now" then my code would work because `0 /* now */ + nano_to_absolute(((UInt64)n/2) * 100ULL * 1000ULL * 1000ULL)` should send the MIDI message that many nanoseconds in the future. 0 actually means "late" because even adding some number that is not equal to the most recent call to AudioGetCurrentHostTime() (which I have only observed return non-zero) still plays the message immediately. I am of course assuming a timestamp of 0 is interpreted as a time and not a flag meaning "send now". It seems to be interpreted as a flag.

Comment: Zero is interpreted as a flag meaning "send now". If the API acted the way that you expected, the argument would be named something like `delay`, not `timestamp`.

Comment: it depends also on the destinations MIDIObjectSet(Get)IntegerProperty. If those properties of the destination or virtual receiver tell it should schedule in advance or even use it at all then you must use timestamps ahead of 0 to make it work. In other words, you may have to set or consider this property when creating the port.